# How to group similar rows in dataset?

Tags: python, dataset, match, fuzzywuzzy

I am trying to think of a good way to combine several datasets where each dataset has a slightly different set of information on the same set of items, and therefore includes slightly different data. For example:

```
+----+------+--------+-------+------------------+----------+---------+---------+
| h  |  db  |  name  |  age  |     location     |  colour  |  fruit  |  height |
+----+------+--------+-------+------------------+----------+---------+---------+
| 1  |  b   |  joe   |   22  |  redbush ave     |  blue    |  pear   |  _      |
| 2  |  b   |  joe   |   22  |  redbush avenue  |  blue    |  paer   |  _      |
| 3  |  c   |  macy  |   38  |  high street     |  green   |  apple  |  1.65   |
| 4  |  c   |  j. h  |   22  |  redbush         |  blue    |  pear   |  1.59   |
+----+------+--------+-------+------------------+----------+---------+---------+
```

From that set of rows (i.e. combined from DB's `b` and `c`, I would like to get:

```
+----+------+-----------+-------+-------------------------------+----------+--------------+---------+
| h  |  db  |  name     |  age  |        location               |  colour  |    fruit     |  height |
+----+-------+--- ------+-------+-------------------------------+----------+--------------+---------+
| 1  |  X   |  joe, j.h |  22   |  redbush ave, redbush avenue  |  blue    |  pear, paer  |    1.59 |
| 2  |  X   |  macy     |  38   |  high street                  |  green   |  apple       |    1.65 |
+----+------+-----------+-------+-------------------------------+----------+--------------+---------+
```

I.e. the 3 fairly similar rows have been combined, and where their data differs, all versions are added.

I am trying to learn python so have found things for pandas, using groupby, concatenating all columns and comparing, and fuzzywuzzy, but nothing quite seems to match. I am guessing that the answer will involve the edit/Levenshtein distance but am struggling to figure out an approach.

Thanks for you help,

Matt